# Why is the Button collector not properly working?

Tags: discord.js

As you can see I'm trying to do a list in form of an embed, where users can sign themselves in, via discord buttons. I already created the buttons and I thought with this code I could do what I wanted, but there are some problems. For example the first press on the buttons always results in a failed interaction. Or when someone else presses a button after I pressed one, he changes my name in the Array. And after some clicks the bot also crashes with the error "DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction" at this function: "await i.update({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });". As I'm new to Programming and stuck for several days now, someone really needs to help me. This is the part of the code, that doesn't work how it should:

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        var users = [];
        var buttonclicker = interaction.member.nickname
        var greenbtnclicker = ' ${buttonclicker}'
        var yellowbtnclicker = ' ${buttonclicker}'
        const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 2147483647 });
            if(!interaction.isButton()) return;          
            collector.on('collect', async (i) => {
                if (i.customId === 'green') {
                    if(users.indexOf(greenbtnclicker) == -1) {
                        if(users.indexOf(yellowbtnclicker) > -1) {
                            var int = users.indexOf(yellowbtnclicker)
                            users.splice(int, 1)
                        }
                        users.push(greenbtnclicker)
                        users.sort();
                        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#208c3d')
                        .setTitle('Active list')
                        .setDescription('Active Players: ${users.length}')
                        .setFooter('Footer')
                        for(var j=0;j < users.length; j++) {
                            newEmbed.addField('--------------------------------', users[j])
                        }
                        await i.update({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Already green')
                    }
                } else if (i.customId === 'red') {
                    if(users.indexOf(yellowbtnclicker) != -1) {
                        var int = users.indexOf(yellowbtnclicker)
                        users.splice(int, 1)
                        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#208c3d')
                        .setTitle('Active list')
                        .setDescription('Active Players: ${users.length}')
                        .setFooter('Footer')
                        for(var j=0;j < users.length; j++) { 
                            newEmbed.addField('--------------------------------', users[j])
                        }
                        await i.update({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
                    } else if(users.indexOf(greenbtnclicker) != -1) {
                        var int = users.indexOf(greenbtnclicker)
                        users.splice(int, 1)
                        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#208c3d')
                        .setTitle('Active list')
                        .setDescription('Active Players: ${users.length}')
                        .setFooter('Footer')
                        for(var j=0;j < users.length; j++) { 
                            newEmbed.addField('--------------------------------', users[j])
                        }
                        await i.update({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
                    } else {               
                        console.log('Already out')             
                    }
                } else if (i.customId === 'yellow') {
                    console.log(users)
                    if(users.indexOf(yellowbtnclicker) == -1) {
                        if(users.indexOf(greenbtnclicker) != -1) {
                            var int = users.indexOf(greenbtnclicker)
                            users.splice(int, 1)
                        }
                        users.push(yellowbtnclicker)
                        users.sort();
                        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#208c3d')
                        .setTitle('Active list')
                        .setDescription('Active Players: ${users.length}')
                        .setFooter('Footer')
                        for(var j=0;j < users.length; j++) { 
                            newEmbed.addField('--------------------------------', users[j])
                        }
                        await i.update({ embeds: [newEmbed], components: [row] });
                    } else {               
                        console.log('Already yellow')             
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

I also have this before the essential code:

```
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

const row = new MessageActionRow()
           .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId("green")
                    .setStyle("SUCCESS")
                    .setLabel("green")
                    .setEmoji(""),
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId("red")
                    .setStyle("DANGER")
                    .setLabel("red")
                    .setEmoji(""),
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId("yellow")
                    .setStyle("SECONDARY")
                    .setLabel("yellow")
                    .setEmoji(""),
            );


client.once("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase() == "!createrecord" && msg.guild && !msg.member.user.bot){
        msg.delete()

        var embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#208c3d')
        .setTitle('Active list')
        .setDescription("No active players")
        .setFooter("Footer")


        msg.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn’t define row, try to define row

Try adding the following code

```
const {
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton

} = require('discord.js');

const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId("buttonsid")
            .setLabel('test!')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
        );
```

Comment: I did, I just didn't show that in the example

Comment: It will fail the first time you press the button, will it happen after that?

Comment: No, but I think it puts the guy in the array, that clicked the button before. It's exactly how I described it in my question

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think I can provide you with an answer